# Modal closing right away

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a modal to my page but it only stays open for a second and then closes again.

Here is my code:

`Home.js`

```
import './Home.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from "./components/Modal";


function Home() {
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    return (

        <div>
            {console.log(openModal)}
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-name">iScore</h1>
                </header>
            </div>

            <div className="Auth-form-container">
                <form className="Auth-form">
                    <div className="Auth-form-content">
                        <h3 className="Auth-form-title">Sign In</h3>
                        <div className="form-group-both">
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Email address: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter email"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group-pass">
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Password: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="popup">
                            <button className="submit"
                            >
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        {openModal && <Modal setOpenModals={setOpenModal}/>}
                        <p className="forgot-password text-right mt-2">
                            Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Need an account?
                        </p>
                        <button className="sign-up" onClick={() => {
                            setOpenModal(true);
                        }}>Register
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Home;
```

`Modal.js`

```
import "./Modal.css";
import {useState} from "react";

function Modal({ setOpenModals }) {

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log("Checked: ", event.target.checked)
        setAgreement(event.target.checked);
    }

    return(
        <div className="modalBackground">
            <div className="modalContainer">
            <article>
                <button className="Close" onClick={() => setOpenModals(false)}> &times; </button>
                    {/*<form>*/}
                        <div className="Auth-form-content">
                            <h3 className="Auth-form-title">Register</h3>
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Email address: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter email"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Email address: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="name"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter first name"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Password: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                <label>Confirm Password: </label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control mt-1"
                                    placeholder="Enter password again"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="yes" onChange={handleChange}/>
                                    <label htmlFor="terms"> I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/*</form>*/}
            </article>
            <footer>
                <button disabled={!agreement} onClick={() => {handleSubmit();setOpenModals(false)}}>Register</button>
                <button onClick={() => setOpenModals(false)} >Close</button>
            </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

It seems that as soon as I press `Register` I can see in the console that `openModal` is set to True, but then immediately gets set back to false.

I am at a bit of a loss as to what to changes to try and make this work. From my perspective it should be doing it correctly.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So, `setAgreement` and `agreement` are missing from the code, and this implies that other code might be missing too, which could be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in `Modal.js` in  `<button disabled={!agreement} onClick={() => {handleSubmit();setOpenModals(false)}}>Register</button>` you use undeclared
`agreement` variable that cause `Modal.js` throw an error and do not render. You need pass `agreement` as prop or add a new state `const [agreement, setAgreement] = useState(false)` or remove `disabled={!agreement}` from a button in `Modal.js`

**Edited**
You have a `form` tag in `Home.js` and when you click `Register` button it opens the Modal AND submits a form. By default, a button has an innate type property of submit. When clicked, or activated inside a form, it will cause that form to submit (and trigger a corresponding submit event). This submit event cause Modal to close. Add `type="button"` to the Register button in `Home.js`.

Comment: I have removed disabled={!agreement} but still no joy. There is no error, the modal does popup for a second so.

Comment: @HLT I edited my answer, now it should work

Comment: That sorted it, thank you so much, that has been driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

at:

```
<button disabled={!agreement} onClick={() => 
{handleSubmit();setOpenModals(false)}}>Register</button>
```

You are calling setOpenModals false right after handleSubmit() which is causing immediate close of modal.

You need to close the modal in handleSubmit() function.

Comment: That should only be called onClick, right? Its not being executed when the modal loads.
Anyhow, I have tried removing that line entirely but it still does not work.